# pyspark: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, pyspark, environment-variables

I just installed pyspark 2.2.0 using conda (using python v3.6 on windows 7 64bit, java v1.8)

```
$conda install pyspark
```

It downloaded and seemed to install correctly with no errors. Now when I run `pyspark` on the command line, it just tells me "The system cannot find the path specified."

```
$pyspark
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I tried including the pyspark path directory in my PATH environment variables, but that still didn't seem to work, but maybe I am giving the wrong path? Can anyone please advise. Does the Java path need to be specified in PATH environment variables or something? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySpark from PyPi (i.e. installed with `pip` or `conda`) does not contain the full PySpark functionality; it is only intended for use with a Spark installation in an already existing cluster, in which case you might want to [avoid downloading the whole Spark distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225169/libraries-needed-to-use-spark-from-python-pyspark?noredirect=1&lq=1). From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable
>   for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone,
>   YARN, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup
>   your own standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version
>   of Spark from the [Apache Spark downloads page](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

If you intend to work in the PySpark shell, I suggest you download Spark as said above (PySpark is an essential component of it).

Comment: Thanks - still having trouble in getting it up and running though, even after downloading from the page. Is it necessary to change PATH variables in the .bashrc as outlined [here](https://blog.sicara.com/get-started-pyspark-jupyter-guide-tutorial-ae2fe84f594f)?

Comment: @killerT2333 In general, yes; you'll find literally dozens of articles in the web for this. And if you found the answer helpful, kindly accept it (upvotes are also welcome) - thanks

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a Java path problem.

I had the same issue and had exactly the same response, and JAVA_HOME path was not set.

Check  [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802384/spark-shell-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/52831841#52831841)  and see Moustafa Mahmoud's answer. I only had to take care of suggestion 1. (JAVA_HOME variable).

Also see  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340941/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error-while-running-pyspark?rq=1)  as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was caused by double path. remove spark path from environment.

```
pip uninstall pyspark
pip install pyspark
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3.5
```

This worked for me when I was having PATH issues. Hope it helps. 
If not, check out your config files.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the compatibility as well , It seems that your spark version is not compatible with the Java Version for example spark-2.4.3 is compatible with java-8.0(jdk-8u51-.../jdk1.8.0_51).