# How to troubleshoot 'pyspark' is not recognized... error on Windows?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

It has been two weeks during which I have been trying to install Spark (pyspark) on my Windows 10 machine, now I realized that I need your help.

When I try to start 'pyspark' in the command prompt, I still receive the following error:

### The Problem

> 'pyspark' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

To me this hints at a problem with the path/environmental variables, but I cannot find the root of the problem.

### My Actions

I have tried multiple tutorials but the best I found was the one by [Michael Galarnyk](https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c). I followed his tutorial step by step:

- Installed Java
- Installed Anaconda
- Downloaded Spark 2.3.1 (I changed the commands accordingly as Michael's tutorial uses a different version) from the official website. I moved it in line with the tutorial in the cmd prompt:

  ```
  mv C:\Users\patri\Downloads\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
  ```

  Then I untarred it:

  ```
  gzip -d spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
  ```

  and

  ```
  tar xvf spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7.tar
  ```
- Downloaded Hadoop 2.7.1 from [Github](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin):

  ```
  curl -k -L -o winutils.exe https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/raw/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe?raw=true
  ```
- Set my Environmental Variables accordingly:

  ```
  setx SPARK_HOME C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
  setx HADOOP_HOME C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
  setx PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON jupyter
  setx PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS notebook
  ```

  Then added *C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin* to my path    variables. My environmental user variables now look like this:
  [Current Environmental Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uILXE.png)

These actions should have done the trick, but when I run `pyspark --master local[2]`, I still get the error from above. Can you help to track down this error using the information from above?

### Checks

I ran a couple of checks in the command prompt to verify the following:

- Java is installed
- Anaconda is installed
- pip is installed
- Python is installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved this issue by setting the variables as "system variables" rather than "user variables".
Note

1. In my case setting variables from command line resulted in "user variables" so I had to use the Advanced settings GUI to enter values as "system variables"
2. You may want to rule out any installation issue, in which case try to cd into C:\opt\spark\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin and run `pyspark master local[2]` (make sure winutils.exe is there); if that does not work then you have other issues than just env variables

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Indeed changing from user to system variables changed it, however now I get the following error: "The system cannot find the path specified". Even though when I manually check with "where python/conda/java etc" It tells me they are there. I googled this error, stackoverflow suggests it's from not [downloading the whole distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849585/pyspark-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I did so following the tutorial. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you try findspark as described here: https://github.com/minrk/findspark? In the meantime can you accept this answer as it addresses the exact issue from the question?

Comment: Thanks for the package, this seams very promising. When I try to run it as suggested in the `ReadMe`, `findspark.init()` an out of range error is returned: **IndexError: list index out of range**.  `findspark.find()` works so I tried `findspark.init(findspark.find())` but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the given steps explained in my blog will resolve your problem-

**How to Setup PySpark on Windows**
https://beasparky.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-setup-pyspark-in-windows.html

**To set up the environment paths for Spark.**

```
Go to "Advanced System Settings" and set below paths
JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"
HADOOP_HOME="C:\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
SPARK_HOME="C:\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
Also, add their bin path into the PATH system variable
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Could you summarize the most important steps out of this blog post? Links tend to change or disappear in the future...

Comment: This is good insight.  Would you have the time to explain how many of these libraries interact?  For example, if the SPARK_HOME is embedded in Anaconda ( C:\Users\mylogin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark ) but also in a spark directory, would there be a different path structure (as above, your spark is in its own folder).