# Pyspark - python path is not recognized

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I followed the instruction for installing pyspark on Windows, but am having a similar issue to [How to troubleshoot 'pyspark' is not recognized... error on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347012/how-to-troubleshoot-pyspark-is-not-recognized-error-on-windows)
But my error message when I type 'pyspark' on cmd is:

```
'C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I've tried installing different python versions (and edited environment variables) but result is the same. Environment variables are set as fllows: 
PYSPARK_PYTHON=C:\Users\simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310
SPARK_HOME=C:\apps\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3
HADOOP_HOME=C:\apps\spark-3.3.0-bin-hadoop3
Can you help track down this error?

Solved:
adding `\python.exe` to PYSPARK_PYTHON solved the problem. It is very strange because every tutorial I saw did not include the .exe but oh well!

Comment: please make sure you installed python correctly

Comment: As @ManojTolagekar said, check if you have installed Python in the `appdata` folder

Comment: check the path for misspellings. or try to copy the path using `shift` + `right click` -> `copy as path`

Answer (score 0):

Adding \python.exe to PYSPARK_PYTHON solved the problem.