# Missing spark-env.sh if I installed pyspark with pip

Tags: pip, pyspark

I installed pyspark 2.2.0 with `pip`, but I don't see a file named `spark-env.sh` nor the `conf` directory. I would like to define variables like `SPARK_WORKER_CORES` in this file. How should I proceed?

I am using Mac OSX El Capitan, python 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySpark from PyPi (i.e. installed with `pip` or `conda`) does not contain the full PySpark functionality; it is only intended for use with a Spark installation in an already existing cluster, in which case you might want to [avoid downloading the whole Spark distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45225169/libraries-needed-to-use-spark-from-python-pyspark?noredirect=1&lq=1). From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark):

> The Python packaging for Spark is not intended to replace all of the
>   other use cases. This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for
>   interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or
>   Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to setup your own
>   standalone Spark cluster. You can download the full version of Spark
>   from the [Apache Spark downloads page](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

So, what you should do is download Spark as said above (PySpark is an essential component of it).